# Bar Chart cannot read data and label in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I'm a beginner working with Chart.js and I'm having a problem with label and data. My chart didn't show up. This is my codes. I'm using laravel framework. And sqlite database.

This is my codes

```
var labelGrafik = [];
        for(var i=0; i<totunsur; i++){
            var arr1 = [];
            var ket = $('#unsur-'+i).val();
            arr1.push(ket);
            labelGrafik.push(arr1);
        }

        var dataGrafik = [];
        for(var i=0; i<totunsur; i++){
            var arr2 = [];
            var value = $('#mean-'+i).val();
            arr2.push(value);
            dataGrafik.push(arr2);
        }

        var barchart = document.getElementById('flot-bar2-chart-ikm');
        var chart = new Chart(barchart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labelGrafik,
            datasets: [{
            label: 'Data Penjualan',
            data: dataGrafik,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2
            }]
        }
        });
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi @FatimahBadriyah can you include your HTML codes as well as I can see you are using $('#unsur-'+i).val() and $('#mean-'+i).val() to get the labels and data for the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your for loop looks malformed in terms of your use of the arr1 and arr2 arrays. Here are edits to your code

```js
var labelGrafik = [];
for(var i=0; i<totunsur; i++){
    var ket = $('#unsur-'+i).val();
    labelGrafik.push(ket);
}

var dataGrafik = [];
for(var i=0; i<totunsur; i++){
    var value = $('#mean-'+i).val();
    dataGrafik.push(value);
}

var barchart = document.getElementById('flot-bar2-chart-ikm');
var chart = new Chart(barchart, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: labelGrafik,
    datasets: [{
    label: 'Data Penjualan',
    data: dataGrafik,
    backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 2
    }]
}
});
```

Comment: It still not working. Should I parse my array to json?

Comment: No need to parse array to json. Do you see any error in the console? Can you post your HTML code of tags which are holding the value or create a fiddle?